# Error: Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm building an app that uses a Cordova plugin for Google Maps. I keep getting this error and have no clue how to fix it or what it even means. Any help would be appreciated. Here's the error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'buildConfigPackageName'.
   > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Amanda/Desktop/project2/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 184; The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:overrideLibrary" associated with an element type "application" is not bound.
```

And my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.example.project2" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" tools:overrideLibrary="za.co.twyst">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="${GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY}" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 
systemId: file:/C:/Users/Amanda/Desktop/project2/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; 
lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 184;
The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:overrideLibrary" associated with an element type "application" is not bound.
```

As you can see the error is in line no 5 and column no 184.As suggested i think you are missing the name space

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Add this to your manifest so that your manifest will look something like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:versionCode="10000"
    android:versionName="1.0.0"
    package="com.example.project2"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" tools:overrideLibrary="za.co.twyst">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="${GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY}" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got another error `Manifest merger failed:uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:tbxml-android:] C:\...\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 14
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,
                or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
                or use tools:overrideLibrary="za.co.twyst" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)` I'm confused.

Comment: what is the min sdk you are using check the build.gradle

Comment: I’m using minSDK 19

Comment: can you please paste your build.gradle